# No Cloud Connector for Heroku's foreman?

Tags: heroku, spring-cloud

I'm trying to run the spring-cloud hello world using Heroku. I'm trying to use foreman and i get the following stacktrace:

```
ERROR 6067 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application startup failed
org.springframework.cloud.CloudException: No suitable cloud connector found
   at org.springframework.cloud.CloudFactory.getCloud(CloudFactory.java:55)
   at org.springframework.cloud.config.CloudScanHelper.initializeCloud(CloudScanHelper.java:85)
   at org.springframework.cloud.config.CloudScanHelper.registerServiceBeans(CloudScanHelper.java:55)
   at org.springframework.cloud.config.java.ServiceScanConfiguration.registerBeanDefinitions(ServiceScanConfiguration.java:22)
   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:122)
   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:318)
   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
   at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
   at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
   at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:692)
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:962)
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:951)
   at com.trident.cloudexmachina.Application.main(Application.java:13)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
   at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there a "foreman" connector i missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i will explain WHY my question is nonsensical and how to 'fix it'.

First, there is a [localconfig-connector](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/tree/master/spring-cloud-localconfig-connector) in the [spring-cloud-connectors](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/tree/master/spring-cloud-localconfig-connector) project. Therefore, you can start your Spring Application "ye old way" using a Main class yadiyadiyada.

However, it does only partially solve the problem, since foreman still should be used to start the application locally "as would do Heroku". You will however need a different Procfile or a different.env file to set up JAVA_OPTS with -Dspring.cloud.appId=myappname as required by the localconfig-connector, like this:

```
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.cloud.appId=myappname
```